# How to eliminate the items in the python list step by step?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am using a 'for loop' to eliminate the item step by step and generate a new list(feature_combination) including different combinations.

```
feature_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
feature_combination = []
for i in range(7):
    feature_list.pop()
    feature_combination.append(feature_list)
feature_combination
```

The ideal output should be:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],['A', 'B', 'C'],['A', 'B'],['A'], []]
```

But the current output is:
`[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]`

When I print the progress step by step:

```
feature_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
feature_combination = []
for i in range(7):
    feature_list.pop()
    print(feature_list)
```

I can get the following the results:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B']
['A']
[]
```

So, why I cannot append these results to an empty list? What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because when you call `feature_combination.append(feature_list)`, you are appending a *reference* to `feature_list`, not the actual value of `feature_list`. Since `feature_list` is empty at the end of the for loop, all of the references to it are empty as well.

You can fix it by changing `feature_combination.append(feature_list)` to `feature_combination.append(feature_list.copy())`, which makes a copy of the list to store.

Comment: Great answer. To the OP, if you want a bit more detail on what is going on, this section of the Python FAQ might be useful - https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x

Answer (score 1):

> A Python variable is a symbolic name that is a reference or pointer to an object. Once an object is assigned to a variable, you can refer to the object by that name. But the data itself is still contained within the object. refer [this](https://realpython.com/python-variables/).

This is because the `feature_list` points to a specific object, which keeps updating as you pop are subsequently. You are basically creating a list that contains [object, object, object ...] all pointing to the same `feature_list` object. As you keep popping and updating the object, the list that collects multiple instances of this same object also gets updated with this object.

Here is how you can test this happening -

```
feature_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
feature_combination = []
for i in range(7):
    feature_list.pop()
    feature_combination.append(feature_list)
    print('iteration', i)
    print(feature_combination) #Print the primary list after each iteration
```

```
iteration 0
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']]
iteration 1
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]
iteration 2
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
iteration 3
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
iteration 4
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B']]
iteration 5
[['A'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A']]
iteration 6
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]`
```

Notice, that after each iteration, every instance of the sublist is being updated after the pop and reflect inside the main list.

#### A fix

A fix is to use a slice to get and store a copy.

```
feature_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
feature_combination = []
for i in range(7):
    feature_list.pop()
    print(feature_list)
    feature_combination.append(feature_list[:]) #<----
feature_combination
```

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['A', 'B'],
 ['A'],
 []]
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, very detailed and helpful!

Comment: glad to help anytime

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to pass an index into pop in order to specify which element to delete. Though I find this unesaccary, instead you could use slicing.
Below is an example of how you could accomplish your goal. This code adjusts to your desired output.

```
feature_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
feature_combination = []
for i in range(7):
    feature_list = feature_list[:-1]
    feature_combination.append(feature_list)
print(feature_combination)
```

**output**

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['A'], []]
```